# Placeholder z-index firefox issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, z-index, placeholder

While using firefox, I have placeholders in a registration input, just above the registration form is my menu, when I hover over the drop-down menu the placeholder appears on top.

I've tried messing about with the z-indexes but this doesn't seem to be the problem. All other parts of the input field are hidden behind the drop-down menu but not the placeholder.

I've also tried adding z-indexes to

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {}
::-moz-placeholder {}
:-ms-input-placeholder {}
input:-moz-placeholder {}
```

but to no avail.

I'd preferably like to achieve this without resorting to Javascript.

[image]

Jsfiddle quick demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/LLANn/1/

Comment: Could please post your html+css?!

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: What browser are you using, looks fine to me on Chrome.

Comment: Good point, it appears it's just a firefox issue

Comment: just another hint: the placeholder values you're using are not valid. e.g. a placeholder value for an email input would be something like mail@example.com

EDIT: ok, you don't use an email input, but nevertheless its value should be an example for what the user has to fill in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give **position: relative** to **#submenu**. It solves the problem.

Any z-index is useless unless accompanied by 'position'.

Answer (score -1):

May be my suggestion will be useful for someone...
In the case if your placeholder element `z-index` is 0 (as default) - set to `#menu`:

```
z-index: 1;
```

In other cases `z-index` of `#menu` should be at least 1 more than placeholder element